# Validating whole number

Tags: c#, asp.net

What would the best solution be to validate for an integer amount.

I am thinking the following.

```
double value = Double.Parse(txtCubes.Text);
    double wholeValue = Math.Round(value);
Console.WriteLine("You added " + wholeValue + " blocks of ice");
```

Is there a better why of making sure an integer value is entered?

Comment: If you don't want to use the markup validator and keep it in-code as you have, consider using `Int32.TryParse` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**compare validator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) for int validation

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" 
 ControlToValidate="youTextBoxID" ErrorMessage="Value must be a whole number" />
```